# LSTM example with MNIST

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently trying to understand the meaning of `outputs` and `states` of the `tf.nn.rnn` function in `tensorflow`:

```
outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

through the [LSTM MNIST tutorial](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.py).

Indeed, with respect to the following tutorial, [Understanding LSTM](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/), I am wondering what correspond to these variables.

In my opinion, `outputs` correspond to the hidden state (denoted as `h_t` in the previous link) but I am not sure.

Thus, I understand that `outputs` is a list of `time_steps` tensors of shape `(batch_size, n_hidden)`. But why does `states` is a a list of `2` tensors of shape `(batch_size, n_hidden)`. Is it just the cell state for the last time step?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an old question.  Sorry if you figured it out already.

The `outputs` are the values coming out of the "top" of your LSTM units in the diagram.  That is the output of your LSTM layer in total.

As you suggest in your question, the hidden states are actually the temporal hidden states that move from one time period to the next.  They are the `C_t` and `h_t` values that move along the time axis as output/input to the unrolled LSTM layer. That is why you get `2` tensors each with size `(batch_size,n_hidden)`

Comment: to clarify, `outputs` represent `y = Vh`, where `V` is a weight matrix and `h` is the hidden state value.

Comment: That is not correct.  y=Vh is over simplifying what is going on in this case. The link in the OP about Understanding LSTM is a good place to better understand what is actually going on inside.  To get the current y, you need the prior time-step hidden state (c and h) and you need the current X vector and then you combine them with the LSTM algorithm to get the next y output.

Comment: it's a simplification, but which part isn't correct? to get to outputs (which is distinct from the hidden state), you need to multiply the hidden state by some matrix V. in turn, the hidden state consists of the previous hidden state (h_{t-1}), some portion of the cell state (c_t), and the current state (X).

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood.  when I see 'Vh', I read a single matrix multiply with a single vector as input (`h`) However, the in LSTM, you have several non-linearities and combinations inside the LSTM unit that need to be considered.  See here: http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/  Additionally, you have two vectors as the prior state (in the sequence dimension) and one in the X direction that need to be considered.  The usual notation includes all these components and I would not generalize to a single `Vh` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory)

Comment: you are correct that, in LSTMs, there are several activations. you are incorrect in saying these other activations (ie forget, save, remember gates) "need to be considered" for the output. these activations manipulate information coming in and out of cell state and working memory (ie hidden state). however, the output `y` depends only on the hidden state, and does not directly interact with these forget/input/output gates.

Comment: for future folks who might be confused by bobak's incorrect challenge, you can see a clean implementation of LSTM outputs [here](https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2016/08/12/lstm-backprop/). this example specifically calculates output `y` from `h`, the hidden state, and not the cell state.